# Beamer template problem: flushright frame subtitle causes spurious extra slide (or worse!)

Tags: beamer

So here is a MWE that illustrates the problem.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\defbeamertemplate{frametitle}{weird}{%
  \insertframetitle\par%
  \rule{\textwidth}{4pt}%
  \flushright%
  \insertframesubtitle\par%
}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[weird]
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Here is the title}
%\framesubtitle{Here is the subtitle}
Here is the text
\pause
Here is more text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This code fails with a:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
```

Commenting out the `\pause` or `\flushright` or uncommenting the `\framesubtitle` allows it to compile. [Commenting out the `\pause` leads to a spurious empty page at the end.]

So my guess is that this is a "wrong mode" problem when the subtitle is empty. But I don't know enough to fix it. Any clues? Or any hints on what to try in order to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where is the sense to use the two macros instead of using the arguments of `frame`?
This works:

```
\begin{frame}{Here is the title}{Here is the subtitle}
```

you should also check for an existing subtitle:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate{frametitle}{weird}{%
  \insertframetitle\par%
  \rule{\textwidth}{4pt}%
  \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty\else
  \flushright%
  \insertframesubtitle\par\fi}
\makeatother
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[weird]
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Here is the title}{}
Here is the text
\pause
Here is more text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\begin{frame}{Title}{}` breaks.

Comment: So does `\begin{frame}{Title}` (i.e. just the one extra argument. As for why use these macros? I read somewhere they are more robust, and I think they're more semantic. [Also, emacs does them automatically...]

Comment: see edit for handling a missing subtitle

Comment: Thanks! So it is a problem with TeX not liking to `\flushright` an empty paragraph, right? Why is this?

Comment: Do you know _why_ beamer doesn't like an empty flushright paragraph? I tried `\flushright\par` in a normal document and it works fine. What goes wrong when it's inside the template?

Comment: I suppose a problem with horizontal and vertical mode, but I am not really sure. The code of beamer is not really user friendly ...